# Programmatically access Supported Cultures and Neutral Language

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight, I'm wanting to programmatically loop through the list of SupportedCultures defined for the project, as well as find the Neutral Language. How might I do this?

Comment: Please don't use keywords in the title, use the tags instead (you already did).

Comment: you want to change user interface every time the user selects other language?, if this is the case then you could create a class that contains all your strings and bind it to your controls, so when the language changes you raise onPropertychange to refresh your controls.

Comment: No, that's not it. I've got some custom handling of how the languages fall back, and it needs to know what languages are supported by the application. At the moment I've got a hard-coded list, but, as per the question, it would be nice to be able to get this from the project directly.

Comment: @DuncanMatheson I am looking for the same piece of code as I need this as well. Did you managed to solve it?